# Using Cmd while simultaneously printing something in another thread

Tags: python, cmd, twisted, python-curses, urwid

I'm trying to implement a simple command line client that accepts messages from a server and prints them to standard output, while the user inputs commands that are translated into server requests. Right now it is done with twisted and Cmd:

```
from sys import stdout
from cmd import Cmd

from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.internet.protocol import Protocol
from twisted.internet.endpoints import TCP4ClientEndpoint, connectProtocol

class MyCmd(Cmd):    
    def __init__(self, client):
        Cmd.__init__(self)
        self.client = client

    def default(self, line):
        client.sendData(line)

    def do_EOF(self, line):
        if reactor.running:
            reactor.stop()
        stdout.write("\n")
        return True


class MyClient(Protocol):
    def dataReceived(self, data):
        stdout.write(data)

    def sendData(self, data):
        self.transport.write(data)
        self.transport.write("\n")

point = TCP4ClientEndpoint(reactor, "localhost", 6004)
client = MyClient()
connectProtocol(point, client)
reactor.callInThread(MyCmd(client).cmdloop)
reactor.run()
```

This needs to be done asynchronously, because the server sometimes just sends unsolicited data to clients.
But this way the text written to stdout by `MyClient.dataReceived` clashes with Cmd's console handling, rendering it almost unusable.

I'm thinking of putting MyCmd and output from MyClient into separate parts of screen by using some kind of console UI library such as Urwid or ncurses.

This thread from 2009 suggests that it might be impossible with Urwid:
http://lists.excess.org/pipermail/urwid/2009-July/000715.html

And this gist that does it with ncurses doesn't work too well for me: https://gist.github.com/interstar/3005137

Is it still possible somehow?